# I want to find the number of child nodes including myself

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

[image]

I want to find the number of child nodes including myself

In the picture below, each node has the number of child nodes count including itself.

Each node type is a dictionary, and child nodes are included in the list of parent nodes.

I want to start with the parent node and get the count for each node

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it using recursive function

```
def count(parent): 
    if parent == NULL:
        return 0
    sum = 1
    for child in parent:
        sum += count(child)
    return sum
```

But I couldn't complete the code.
As I don't know your object format so I couldn't get child object from your parent object.